# Assign values in a loop in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have this setup here:

```vb
'highest number of days and lowest
niedrigsterTag = 8
hoechsterTag = 8

dim tageV(), tageB()
redim tageV(7), tageB(7)

'day-mapping
tageV(0) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Mo", 1)
tageV(1) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Di", 2)
tageV(2) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Mi", 3)
tageV(3) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Do", 4)
tageV(4) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Fr", 5)
tageV(5) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Sa", 6)
tageV(6) = 7

'for example: mo - fr
for each item in tageV
    'save smallest weekday
    if(isNumeric(item)) then
        if(item <= niedrigsterTag) then
            niedrigsterTag = item
            Response.write(niedrigsterTag)
            response.end()
        end if
    end if
next
```

As you might see, I'm pretty new into classic ASP. I don't understand what I'm missing on my loop. In pseudocode, it looks fine:

> for each numeric value in my array, check if the current value of item is <= the current maxValue (hoechsterTag) - which is in the first iteration 8. If so, override the current value.

Now I'm stuck. I added a `response.end()` in the most-inner `if`. However, **niedrigsterTag** has a value of `7` instead of `1`. Also, during the 1st iteration, `item` should be 1, right? For me it is 7. I imagined `response.end()` is an equivalent to PHP's `die()`

**What I'm trying to realize:**

> if current iteration < current value, override it, so I'm ending up with the smallest value.

I know this is pretty basic, and so far I hadn't problems doing stuff like this in other languages. Don't know why this makes it so special.

Thank you for any hints and advices

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning the values to your tageV array, you are assigning them as strings and then comparing them to integers.  You need to compare like datatypes for one.

Also, they way it is written is like this:  In the first iteration, if the item is 1 and niedrigsterTag is 8 then niedrigsterTag is changed to 1 and response.end stops the loop and exits.  What you need is more like this:

```
'highest number of days and lowest
niedrigsterTag = 8
hoechsterTag = 8

dim tageV(), tageB()
redim tageV(7), tageB(7)

'day-mapping
tageV(0) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Mo", 1)
tageV(1) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Di", 2)
tageV(2) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Mi", 3)
tageV(3) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Do", 4)
tageV(4) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Fr", 5)
tageV(5) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Sa", 6)
tageV(6) = 7

'for example: mo - fr
for each item in tageV
    'save smallest weekday
    if(CInt(item) <= niedrigsterTag) then
            niedrigsterTag = CInt(item)
    end if
next  

Response.write("niedrigsterTag = " & niedrigsterTag)
```

This loops through the array and every time it finds a smaller value, the variable is assigned that value.  Once the loop is done, the variable will hold the smallest value.

By the way, the reason you were getting 7 was because that was the only value that was making it past the if statements.